# $P_R$ is projective and local $\implies$ $End_R(P)$ is local

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

A right $R$-module $P$ is said to be projective if for any epimorphism of right $R$-modules, say $g:B \longrightarrow C$ and any $R$-homomorphism $h:P \longrightarrow C$, there exists $h':P \longrightarrow B$ such that $h=g\circ h'$.

A right $R$-module $P$ is said to be local if $P$ has a largest submodule.

I want to prove the following assertion:

> If $P$ is projective and local, then $P$ is endolocal (i.e. $\mathrm{End}_R(P)$ is local).

I don't know how should I start to proof. A few good hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Prove that the non-units of $\mathrm{End}_R(P)$ form an ideal.

Comment: @bozcan: Do you mean a _unique_ largest submodule?

Comment: Largest submodule of $P$ is a submodule which contains all submodulus of $P$. Hence it must be unique.

Comment: Also, consider the endomorphism ring modulo its Jacobson radical.

Comment: Thanks @user3267, I have read the characterization of local rings. The first comment you write above will be useful.

Comment: You have to show that $\mathrm{End}_R(P)/\mathrm{Jac} \cong \mathrm{End}_R(P/J(P))$.

Answer (score 1):

Proposition: if $f:P\to P$ is an $R$ endomorphism, then $f$ is surjective iff it is an isomorphism. (Apply projectivity directly to get the inverse.)

Corollary: the nonunits of $End_R(P)$ map $P$ into the maximum submodule. Thus that set is additively closed and forms an ideal. This matches a characterization suggested in the comments.